# Vue Warn the client side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to loop a tr within a table with Vue.js and Nuxt. But when I load the page I get the following error

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered
>   virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is
>   likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting
>   block-level elements inside
>
> , or missing . Bailing hydration
>   and performing full client-side render.

When I remove the table from the following block of code from my HTML the error disappears. How can this be happening? I checked all closing tags and they seem to be matching. What is happening here?

**In Template**

```
<template>
  <ContentBlock id="statistics" class="content-light"> 
      <div class="content-grid-light">
          <div class="content-grid-item-1">
              <div>
                  <table class="table">
                      <tr v-for="(statistic, index) in statistics" :key="index" :value="statistic">
                        <th class="table-cell">{{statistic.key}}</th>
                        <td class="table-cell statistic-value">{{statistic.value}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </ContentBlock>
</template>
```

**In Script**

```
  data(){
    return{
      statistics: [
        {key:"TestKey1", value:"TestValue1"},
        {key:"TestKey2", value:"TestValue2"},
        {key:"TestKey3", value:"TestValue3"},
        {key:"TestKey4", value:"TestValue4"},
      ],
    }
  },
```

Here is my rendered html

[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmXuv.png)

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the version of your nuxt project. If the version is v<2.9.0, wrap your table with no-ssr tag. Otherwise use client-only tag like below:

version < 2.9.0:

```
<no-ssr>
   <table></table>
</no-ssr>
```

version > 2.9.0

```
<client-only>
  <table></table>
</client-only>
```

Tip: pay attention that no-ssr is going to be removed in nuxt 3.

Comment: this won't work If you are using a version of Nuxt < v2.9.0, in that case use <no-ssr>

Comment: <no-ssr> is going to be removed in Nuxt 3.

Comment: so Im going to edit my answer according to the version

Comment: That just disables SSR

Answer (score 2):

Marvin Rudolph helped me out on the Nuxt discord. I needed to add a tbody around my tr and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

make sure to wrap your component markup with a template/container no other element should be outside the template/container.
for example:

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
     <table class="table">
      <tr v-for="(statistic, index) in statistics" :key="index" :value="statistic">
        <th class="table-cell">{{statistic.key}}</th>
        <td class="table-cell statistic-value">{{statistic.value}}</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
</template>
```

no element should be outside the #app tag

Comment: I have that. I only gave the table part because that seemed relevant. But I added the full template. And I get the error with that.

Answer (score 0):

The object you are trying to loop over is not correct as it should be for a v-for the rendered html shows [object Object] as value of each  tag, try this instead

```
<template>
  <ContentBlock id="statistics" class="content-light"> 
      <div class="content-grid-light">
          <div class="content-grid-item-1">
              <div>
                  <table class="table">
                      <tr v-for="(statistic, index) in statistics" :key="statistic.key" :value="statistic.value">
                         <th class="table-cell">{{statistic.key}}</th>
                         <td class="table-cell statistic-value">{{statistic.value}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </ContentBlock>
</template>
```

if this does not solves the problem you can use the  tag as suggested [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1700)

Comment: But I want this to be server side rendered. Why couldn't it be?

Comment: @OneDayFly the object you are trying to loop over is not correct as it should be for a `v-for` the rendered html shows [object Object] as value of each `<tr>` tag

Comment: I want it to be server side rendered or have a good reason why it couldn't be done.

Comment: @OneDayFly answer is updated please check now everything will be server side rendered

Comment: Here is the rendered html https://snipboard.io/CtE4Nr.jpg that still generates the error

Comment: seems like a data issue in object for testKey6 how can the value be testValue7 ?

[Screenshot](https://snipboard.io/ykFtn7.jpg)

Comment: No just a typo sorry also I added more test data. The data checks out!