# Array list from AsyncData/fetch rendered by v-for throw: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js for my application. In one of my pages I use `AsyncData` to asynchronously fetch an array of data objects from my Api, which I render in my template using `v-for`. This is working fine when I **don't** use `nuxt-link` or `<a href=".."></a>` **inside** the `v-for`. As soon as I include `nuxt-link` or `<a href=".."></a>` inside my `v-for`, I get the following error:

```
The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. 
This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. 
Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

A basic example of what I try to accomplish:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div
    class="place-card"
    :key="place._id"
    v-for="place in places"
  >
    <nuxt-link
      :to="{
        name: 'places-title',
        params: { title: place.title }
      }"
    >
      <PlaceCard :place="place" />
    </nuxt-link>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  asyncData() {
    // Some preprocessing
    return { places: [{...}, ..., {...}] }
  }
}
</script>
```

I was able to get it working, when I wrap the whole `v-for` div into `<client-only>...</client-only>` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re/61375490#61375490) in @Mohsens answer as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948635/vue-warn-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-render).

Unfortunately, `<client-only></client-only>` prevents server-side-rendering of the async data. However, I do need pre-fetching my data on the server-side, because of SEO.

Does anyone know another solution for this problem?

**EDIT 12.10.2020**
[Extended log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNWsQ.png)

Original code of `PlaceCard` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
    <img :src="place.images[0]" :alt="place.title" class="w-full h-40" />
    <div class="px-6 pt-4">
      <div class="font-bold text-base">{{ place.title }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="px-6 pb-4">
      <nuxt-link :to="'/'"
        >#{{ place.placeType.split(' ').join('') }}</nuxt-link
      >
      <nuxt-link :to="'/'">#{{ place.address.country }}</nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="'/'" v-if="place.vegan">#vegan</nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="'/'" v-else>#not-vegan</nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="'/'" v-if="place.vegetarian">#vegetarian</nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="'/'" v-else>#not-vegetarian</nuxt-link>
    </div>
    <div class="author flex items-center py-3 px-6">
      <div class="user-logo">
        <img
          class="w-8 h-8 object-cover rounded-full mr-2 shadow"
          :src="place.creator.photoURL"
          :alt="place.creator.displayName"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="block text-xs">
        Added by<a href="#" class="ml-1">{{
          place.creator.displayName.split(' ').join('')
        }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    place: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is in `<PlaceCard :place="place" />` ? can you send photo of expanded log `Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes` from console?

Comment: `PlaceCard` is a custom component. I also just printed a text inside the `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>` which was not working.

Comment: I appended the image in the original question. If there is any confusion with the actual code I use, I can also provide the original code to you. In the question I tried to minify the code to the actual problem as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259464/12590382) and [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1815), I had a nested link, the one inside my `v-for` div and another inside my `PlaceCard` component, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Template should only contain 1 element thats fine. But you should not loop the top parent element. Try to wrap it in an div

```
<div>
  <div
    class="place-card"
    :key="place._id"
    v-for="place in places"
  >
    <nuxt-link
      :to="{
        name: 'places-title',
        params: { title: place.title }
      }"
    >
      <PlaceCard :place="place" />
    </nuxt-link>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my original code, I do have a containing element around the v-for div. Unfortunately, this cannot be the problem.